# Как исправить missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, tkinter

Пытаюсь разобраться в основах `tkinter` и при написании кода столкнулся с проблемой:

> TypeError: add_new_dealer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, RIGHT, BOTH, RAISED

All_objects = []

class Add_dealer(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Это всплывающее окно")
        self.btn_close_add_dealer = tk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        self.btn_add_dealer_name = tk.Button(self, text="Добавить", command=self.add_new_dealer())
        self.txt_field_dealer_name = tk.Entry(self, width=10)


        self.txt_field_dealer_name.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        self.label.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.btn_add_dealer_name.pack(pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        self.btn_close_add_dealer.pack(pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)

    def add_new_dealer(self, parent):
        self.new_dealer_name = self.txt_field_dealer_name.get()
        All_objects.append(self.new_dealer_name)
        print(All_objects)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_open_add_dealer = tk.Button(self, text="Добавить поставщика",
                                             command=self.open_window_add_dealer)
        self.btn_open_add_dealer.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

    def open_window_add_dealer(self):
        window_add_dealer = Add_dealer(self)
        window_add_dealer.grab_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ошибка с использованием классов не связана. А с чем связана написано в самой ошибке.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен, если скажете как исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, RIGHT, BOTH, RAISED

All_objects = []

class Add_dealer(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Это всплывающее окно")
        self.btn_close_add_dealer = tk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        self.btn_add_dealer_name = tk.Button(
            self, 
            text="Добавить", 
            command=self.add_new_dealer                             # --- ()
        )
        self.txt_field_dealer_name = tk.Entry(self, width=10)


        self.txt_field_dealer_name.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        self.label.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.btn_add_dealer_name.pack(pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        self.btn_close_add_dealer.pack(pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)

    def add_new_dealer(self):                                       # --- , parent):
        self.new_dealer_name = self.txt_field_dealer_name.get()
        All_objects.append(self.new_dealer_name)
        print(All_objects)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_open_add_dealer = tk.Button(self, text="Добавить поставщика",
                                             command=self.open_window_add_dealer)
        self.btn_open_add_dealer.pack(padx=50, pady=20)

    def open_window_add_dealer(self):
        window_add_dealer = Add_dealer(self)
        window_add_dealer.grab_set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало как хотел

Comment: @Vladimir Kalinin пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @VladimirKalinin [Что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка означает, что при вызове функции `add_new_dealer()` не хватает аргументов.
То есть в `init` у вас передается

```py
....
self.btn_add_dealer_name = tk.Button(self, text="Добавить", command=self.add_new_dealer())
.....
```

Но еще не хватает входного аргумента для функции. Нужен какой то `parent`, выглядеть должно как то так

```py
...., command=self.add_new_dealer(parent))
```

Либо здесь убрать входной аргумент

```py
def add_new_dealer(self):
    self.new_dealer_name = self.txt_field_dealer_name.get()
    All_objects.append(self.new_dealer_name)
    print(All_objects)
```

Comment: @VladimirKalinin я предположил, посмотрите другой ответ